# Gui application for perl scripts and cshell

Tags: gui, ide, perl, tcsh

I am a very green to Linux. I am now taking a course at my studies basic of Linux.
As part of my assessment I need to do some Perl scripts and C shell.  But also we have been asked to build a GUI app that will launch those scripts providing them as an input the strings the user will enter via GUI.

I am familiar with C, C# and Java: what is the best way for me to develop a simple GUI in IDE that you just grab a button or whatever you need and place it on your screen and then just code? (I'm running Ubuntu 64-bit.)

Comment: This is not the right place to ask that kind of thing; please consider reading the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

You can work with both languages in [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/c.php) (gui software development) with the [Epic IDE](http://www.epic-ide.org/) plugin. Eclipse also supports Java. If you want to use C# in eclipse I would recommend the [Emonic](http://emonic.sourceforge.net/) plugin